# Get current post data into array?

Tags: posts, get-post

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to get_page($id), but with the current post acting as the argument for get_post(). Something like this pseudocode: `get_post($this=>ID);` .

Seems simple, but I can't find the it in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `get_post()`, it returns the current post if no ID is specified.

[`get_the_ID()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L20) actually does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893435/getting-the-wordpress-post-id-of-current-post

```
$id = get_the_ID();
var_dump(get_post($id));
```